# Pass Docker arguments to Spring boot properties

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

In a project locally that I've created to test passing Docker arguments to my spring boot `application.properties` I have in the `application.properties`: `test.name=${name}`

and in the application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestServiceApplication {

    @Value("${test.name}")
    private String test;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "test")
    public String getTest() {
        return this.test;
    }
}
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG NAME
ENV TEST_NAME=${NAME}
RUN echo $TEST_NAME
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
RUN echo JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Building it with `sudo docker build -t gs-rest-service --build-arg NAME=Alex .` This works fine locally

Now on a different project my `application.properties`:

```
bulk.api.username=${BULK_USERNAME}
bulk.api.password=${BULK_PASSWORD}
```

and my Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8 AS build

ARG ARTIFACTORY_USER
ARG ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD

WORKDIR /build
COPY . .

RUN mvn -s settings.xml clean package

ARG BULK_USERNAME
ARG BULK_PASSWORD
ENV BULK_API_USERNAME=${BULK_USERNAME}
ENV BULK_API_PASSWORD=${BULK_PASSWORD}
RUN echo $BULK_API_PASSWORD

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/cd-graph-import
COPY --from=build /build/target/abc-svc.jar .

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "abc-svc.jar"]
```

My spring boot class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplication {

    @Value("${bulk.api.username}")
    private String bulkApiUsername;

    @Value("${bulk.api.password}")
    private String bulkApiPassword;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder().basicAuthentication(bulkApiUsername, bulkApiPassword).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "bulkApiUrl")
    public String getBulkApiUrl() {
        return this.bulkApiUrl;
    }
}
```

When this runs in gitlab with:

```
docker build -t $SERVICE_IMAGE --build-arg ARTIFACTORY_USER=$ARTIFACTORY_USER --build-arg ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD=$ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD --build-arg BULK_USERNAME=$BULKAPI_USERNAME --build-arg BULK_PASSWORD=$BULKAPI_PASSWORD .
```

I see that `$BULK_API_PASSWORD` is set properly but when running the application I get the error: `Error creating bean with name

```
'someApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BULK_USERNAME' in value "${BULK_USERNAME}"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: just a subtle difference but in the working case it is `${name}` (lower case!) ..whereas non-working it is ... upper case! (please try this simple fix) ..in application.properties and then maybe even not `${FOO_BAR}`, but `${foo.bar}`.

Comment: That's not it. I also replaced the placeholders in my working example and it still works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to spring [boot application properties docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), you are able to set application properties by an environment variable. You should make env variable with the same name as a property name but if you use env variable, it's recommended to use '_' instead of '.'. For example if you want to set `test.name` you have to set `TEST_NAME` env argument.

In the first example, you set `TEST_NAME` env parameter in your docker file. When your application is starting, spring gets property from env variable (spring gets `TEST_NAME`, not `NAME` variable) and passes to the application, which replaces your default value "${name}". Please note here that spring not inject `NAME` variable, but replace property `test.name` by value from env variable.

In the second case, you haven't set `BULK_API_USERNAME` and `BULK_API_PASSWORD` env properties and spring doesn't replace default values and use `${API_USERNAME}` and `${API_PASSWORD}` as a properties value. You should set `BULK_API_USERNAME` and `BULK_API_PASSWORD` for passing your values to the app.

And also leave the value of properties in application.properties are empty. 'bulk.api.username=' and 'bulk.api.password='

Comment: yes sorry, that was a mistake cause I was renaming the fields. I changed them now and also changed it to what you suggested, but as updated above I still get `'Could not resolve placeholder 'BULK_USERNAME' in value "${BULK_USERNAME}"`

Comment: Could you show how do you inject the value in your app? Do you use @Variable? If yes, what argument do you use?

Comment: I added it. I'm using `@Value` just like the other one

Comment: Could you show the value that you pass to the annotation `@Value`?

Comment: I've added it above in the question `@Value("${bulk.api.username}")`. In fact I replaced the the fields in my working example with the one that is not working and there its fine. It's like the additional steps in my Dockerfile are screwing it up.

Comment: Ok, let's try to leave the value of properties in `application.properties` are empty. 'bulk.api.username=' and 'bulk.api.password='

Comment: 1. In my non working example: At least it doesn't complain that the injection of the field is failing, but I have another irrelevant error regarding the kafka boostrap server (no wories about that)
2. In my working example: I also tried it, and there the field is still passed although I removed the placeholder from the `application.properties`.

Comment: Wow yes! this is it. your comment is the solution. OMG, thank you so much, you have no idea how many hours I was breaking my head over this. You can update your answer with the empty `applicaiton.properties`. I will consider it as answered.

Comment: I am happy that I have helped you!

Comment: Actually the real reason why it was not working in the first place was because I was deploying it in kubernetes and the environment variable had to be set there. Otherwise it would have worked. The working example I only deployed locally without k8s. But thank you anyway, your proposals are still right, I just wanted to mention that.

Comment: Oh, nice to hear it. I still think why your first option haven't worked, cause it have looked correct.